Docker host IP address from inside container is wrong
I have tried following any existing questions regarding this particular issue, but my symptoms are not at all the same.
I am using Docker on Windows. My container is a linux-container. I want to be able to access my host machine's LAN IP address from inside the container. For this, I read that host networking needs to be enabled, or I can use "add-hosts".
Here's what happens if I try to use "add-host".
docker run --rm --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway --network host busybox ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (192.168.65.254): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.65.254: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.965 ms

As you can see, the IP address is 192.168.65.254.
However, if I run ipconfig on the host, my IP address is 192.168.86.59, which I verified to be correct.
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter LAN-forbindelse* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter LAN-forbindelse* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::626a:c22c:921a:3c08%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.59
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.86.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth-netværksforbindelse:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall)):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f2e8:da85:be4c:406e%43
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.176.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

If I run the following command in the container, I also get some weird IP addresses that don't exist:
> ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
addr:172.17.0.1
addr:192.168.65.3
addr:192.168.65.6

This is strange to me, as all guides that I followed are saying that this should work.
How can I get the proper host IP address from within the container?

A container runs in an isolated network environment.  If you're using Docker Desktop, that further runs in a Linux VM.  If the host IP address is important to your application (why?) then running it in an isolated environment like this might not work well.

You shouldn't be adding this entry from --add-host with Docker Desktop. That's only needed for the native Linux installs.

@DavidMaze the "why" of this is that I am in a DevContainer. One of my applications I am developing is an app. That app runs on my phone, but still needs to be able to reach my backend inside the DevContainer on my local machine over WIFI.
